# Laravel Queue: exit queue upon job/task error

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue

I'm using Laravel Queues (against Redis) to process a number of actions that are dependent on one another (ie: they have to be processed sequentially).

Is there any way to halt/exit/quit queue processing for a given queue if any job/task it attempts to process fails (ie: throws an exception)? I've googled a bit but couldn't find anything other than resuming/continuing processing which is obviously not what I need.

Comment: you mean like "job chaining"?

Comment: This is not like job chaining but rather a continues stream of (essentially identical) actions which are pushed to the queue ... if any such action fails, the queue should stop processing.

Comment: This seems like a weird job design, if you want what you want go for job chaining. Else if jobs are seperated they should be able to execute separately imo. A super hacky aproach, use redis as a cache, throw a key blockqueueforx and set the timeout. Before the job executes, check if that key is set and kill the job.